# Rust: Is it safe to cast a mutable borrow to a pointer and back (to placate the borrow checker), if I know that there will only be one instance of it?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, unsafe

I have a program that uses a QuadTree. This tree stores mutable borrows to data that is owned by another container (a Vec). I rebuild the QuadTree every game loop, but I do not want to reallocate, so I `clear` the underlying Vecs of the QuadTree instead of reconstructing it from scratch.

A simplified example that demonstrates the same problem is shown below. Instead of a QuadTree, here I am just using another Vec as this has identical issues.

```
struct A;
fn main() {
    let mut owned_data = vec![A, A, A];
    let mut mut_borrowed_data = vec![];
    
    '_outer: loop {
        mut_borrowed_data.clear();
        '_inner: for borrow in &mut owned_data {
            mut_borrowed_data.push(borrow);
        }
    }
}
```

This gives the error:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `owned_data` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src\main.rs:8:30
  |
8 |         '_inner: for borrow in &mut owned_data {
  |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `owned_data` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
```

The issue isn't really that I am mutably borrowing in a previous iteration of the outer loop. If I remove the `mut_borrowed_data.push(data);` it compiles, because the borrow checker realises that the mutable borrow of `owned_data` is dropped at the end of each outer loop, therefore the number of mutable borrows is a max of 1. By pushing into `mut_borrowed_data`, this mutable borrow is *moved* into this container (Please correct me if I am wrong here), therefore it isn't dropped and the borrow checker is not happy. If I did not have the `clear` there would be multiple copies of the mutable borrow, and the borrow checker is not smart enough to realise that I only push into the `mut_borrowed_data` once, and that I `clear` it every outer loop.

But as it stands, there is only one instance of the mutable borrow at any one time, so is the following code safe/sound?

```
struct A;
fn main() {
    let mut owned_data = vec![A, A, A];
    let mut mut_borrowed_data = vec![];
    
    '_outer: loop {
        mut_borrowed_data.clear();
        '_inner: for borrow in &mut owned_data {
            let ptr = borrow as *mut A;
            let new_borrow = unsafe { &mut *ptr };
            mut_borrowed_data.push(new_borrow);
        }
    }
}
```

This now compiles. The mutable borrow of `owned_data` (named `borrow`) is not moved into the `mut_borrowed_data` and therefore it is dropped at the end of the outer loop. This means `owned_data` is only mutable borrowed once. The unsafe code *takes a copy of the pointer to the data, dereferences it and creates a new borrow to that.* (again, please correct me if I am wrong). Because this uses a copy and not a move, the compiler allows `borrow` and `new_borrow` to exist at the same time. This use of unsafe could break the borrow rules, but as long as I do not use `borrow` after I have created `new_borrow`, and as long as I clear `mut_borrowed_data`, then I think this is safe/sound.

Moreover, (I think) the guarantees given by the borrow checker still hold *as long as I clear the mut_borrowed_data vec*. It won't let me push into `mut_borrowed_data` twice in one loop, because the `new_borrow` is moved after it is first inserted.

I do not want to use a `RefCell` as I want this to be as performant as possible. The whole purpose of the QuadTree is to increase performance so I want to make any overhead it introduces as lean as possible. Incrementing the borrow count is probably cheap, but the branch (to check if that value is <= 1), the indirection, and the decreased simplicity of my data, are too much for me to feel happy about.

Is my use of unsafe here safe/sound? Is there anything that could trip me up?

Comment: I think this is sound. `slice::split_at_mut` does essentially the same thing, using unsafe to guarantee that two &muts obtained from the same container do not overlap.

Comment: @IvanC Thank you for the speedy reply. Is my understanding of how the borrows and moves work correct? I would be more confident using this if I knew exactly why it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with that: your code is safe, and also pretty sound.

> The unsafe code takes a copy of the pointer to the data, dereferences it and creates a new borrow to that. (again, please correct me if I am wrong). Because this uses a copy and not a move, the compiler allows `borrow` and `new_borrow` to exist at the same time.

This is not accurate. The reason `borrow` and `new_borrow` can exist at the same time is not because raw pointers are copied while references are moved, but because when you converted the reference to a raw pointer you detached the lifetime chain - the compiler can no longer track the source of `new_borrow`.

> It won't let me push into `mut_borrowed_data` twice in one loop, because the `new_borrow` is moved after it is first inserted.

Yes, but also no:

```rust
'_outer: loop {
    mut_borrowed_data.clear();
    '_inner: for borrow in &mut owned_data {
        let ptr = borrow as *mut A;
        let new_borrow = unsafe { &mut *ptr };
        mut_borrowed_data.push(new_borrow);
        mut_borrowed_data.push(new_borrow);
    }
}
// Does not compile:
// error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `new_borrow`
//   --> src/lib.rs:12:32
//    |
// 10 |         let new_borrow = unsafe { &mut *ptr };
//    |             ---------- move occurs because `new_borrow` has type `&mut A`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
// 11 |         mut_borrowed_data.push(new_borrow);
//    |                                ---------- value moved here
// 12 |         mut_borrowed_data.push(new_borrow);
//    |                                ^^^^^^^^^^ value borrowed here after move

// However, this does compile, and it is still Undefined Behavior:
'_outer: loop {
    mut_borrowed_data.clear();
    '_inner: for borrow in &mut owned_data {
        let ptr = borrow as *mut A;
        let new_borrow = unsafe { &mut *ptr };
        mut_borrowed_data.push(new_borrow);
        eprintln!("{borrow}"); // Use the old `borrow`.
    }
}
```

You can make it a bit safer by shadowing the original `borrow`, so it can no longer be used:

```rust
'_outer: loop {
    mut_borrowed_data.clear();
    '_inner: for borrow in &mut owned_data {
        let borrow = unsafe { &mut *(borrow as *mut A) };
        mut_borrowed_data.push(borrow);
    }
}
```

But it is still not perfect. The reason is that since you detach the lifetime, you get an unlimited, essentially `'static` reference. This means it can be used longer than allowed, for example:

```rust
use std::sync::Mutex;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct A;

static EVIL: Mutex<Option<&'static mut A>> = Mutex::new(None);

fn main() {
    let mut owned_data = vec![A, A, A];
    let mut mut_borrowed_data = vec![];
    
    '_outer: loop {
        if let Some(evil) = EVIL.lock().unwrap().as_deref_mut() {
            eprintln!("HaHa! We got two overlapping mutable references! {evil:?}");
        }
        
        mut_borrowed_data.clear();
        '_inner: for borrow in &mut owned_data {
            let borrow = unsafe { &mut *(borrow as *mut A) };
            mut_borrowed_data.push(borrow);
        }
        
        *EVIL.lock().unwrap() = mut_borrowed_data.pop();
    }
}
```

This does not mean this approach is bad (it is probably what I would use) but you need to be careful.

Comment: Am I correct that this problem inherently requires unsafe, or dynamic borrow checking rules? The advice I often see in forums is that 99% of the time you can use safe rust to achieve the same results by rethinking the design.
But here I inherently need to move borrowed data into a container owned by an outer scope, therefore the  borrow checker will never be able to understand that this container only has one copy of the borrow. The container must be owned by an outer scope, as I need the capacity to persist between usages. Is my wording / understanding of this problem correct?

Comment: @Blue7 I think it is possible to encapsulate this pattern in a safe and sound API, but I have to implement it to be sure...

Comment: @Blue7 [Here it is](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=88ba5538bc55ca0ed894267122a1587c). I believe it is sound.

Comment: @Blue7 Hmm... I'm not so sure anymore it is sound. But I believe it is possible to make it sound.

Comment: This is all really interesting! Thank you so much for your time helping me with this. My understanding of the language is improving.